# ajax.actionlink vs javascript which calls first

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has an Ajax.Actionlink and at the same time, I have a .click event in javascript on the same Ajax.Actionlink. When I click the action link, does the ajax run first or does the .click event in the javascript?

I would add examples, but I believe the question is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what happens is that `Ajax.ActionLink` cancels the default action in order to send the ajax request. You might add the onclick event in the [OnBegin option of Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Might it depend on where the .click event is bound?  Try adding a console.log() to both events and see which order they are called.